# Making jerkies less salty

Tags: salt, marinade, jerky

So yesterday I made my first ever home-made jerky. It tastes great (I suppose I followed a good recipe).

However, it is quite salty. I thought I didn't use a lot of salt, but I did use a lot of soy sauce.

I heard that the saltiness is important for curing the food. What should I do then?

Comment: It seems like what the other question you want to ask here is "how much salt is necessary to properly cure the jerky?" - it's quite possible the recipe went overboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also crust the meat with salt, removing the crust after dehydrating (or smoking).  The goal is to

- pull the moisture out, and
- to season

Note that traditionally, some bacons and hams are preserved by burying the meat in coarse salt, then hanging + smoking.  You can jerk in the same manner, by using salt to pull out the moisture, then remove from the salt (or remove the surface salt) and dehydrate. The trick is in balancing the need to remove the moisture, and the desired flavour.

Answer (score 2):

Try using low-sodium soy sauce, or possibly teriyaki sauce instead. You might also try reducing the amount of salt but increasing the curing time.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it yet, but someone suggested dicing potato and putting it in with the marinde. I'm not sure if its the starch from the potato or the absorbtion that does it.